# Web Site Administration Tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to follow a tutorial on creating a log in system and adding users in asp.net and i cant seem to work out how to use the apparently outdfated or expired Web Site Administration Tool. is there a new equivalent tool i can use or is there some way to get it to work as i cant seem to get it working using the command prompt.

I have tried entering this into the command prompt which works fine in order to rune iisexpress:

```
"C:\Program Files\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" /path:c:\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles /vpath:"/asp.netwebadminfiles" /port:8089 /clr:4.0 /ntlm
```

I then enter the following into my browser:

```
http://localhost:8089/asp.netwebadminfiles/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=[Exact_Project_Path]\&applicationUrl=/
```

Where the project path is set to my project path but get the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: The parameter 'PhysicalDirectory' is invalid. Parameter name: PhysicalDirectory at System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping.set_PhysicalDirectory(String value) at System.Web.Configuration.VirtualDirectoryMapping..ctor(String physicalDirectory, Boolean isAppRoot) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.OpenWebConfiguration(String path, String appPhysPath, Boolean getWebConfigForSubDir) at System.Web.Administration.WebAdminPage.VerifyAppValid()

This to me seems to be that the path i enter is invalid but i have tried every different entry surrouding my solution.

Is there a new or better answer to creating a log in system with asp without all this fuss?

Very new to all this so please take it easy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look through https://www.asp.net/identity, and in particular the [Introduction to ASP.NET Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) post, which gives an overview of the older ASP.NET Membership and the newer ASP.NET Identity.  Identity is supposed to be a lot easier to integrate into your app.

Comment: thankyou for the response, i see how it is totally different now. would you say it was worth using the template with the user accounts pre-set or whether i should try to add it to my own project. i'm a huge beginner so im not sure how id even go about this.

Comment: @DanielTurville If you just want to get a site running with users, I'd say to use the template and focus on making your site.  You can dig into how it works when you're more comfortable, or when you bump into issues.